# How to make radio button select multiple values at once in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am working on this project where I need to have some radio button from api and I need radio button to be select multiple times at once. For ex: Let's say there are 4 options and user can select more than one option at one time. How do I make that? How to make radio button select multiple values at once?

```
 Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      flex: 2,
                                      child: Containers(
                                        height: size.height,
                                        child: Radio(
                                          activeColor: radioButtonItem ==
                                                  _data[index].name
                                              ? Colors.white
                                              : const Color.fromRGBO(
                                                  44, 39, 36, 0.75),
                                          value: _data[index].id,
                                          groupValue: id,
                                          onChanged: (val) {
                                            setState(
                                              () {
                                                radioButtonItem =
                                                    _data[index].name;
                                                id = _data[index].id;
                                              },
                                            );
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      flex: 5,
                                      child: Containers(
                                        height: size.height,
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: [
                                            Texts(
                                              texts: _data[index].name,
                                              fontSize: 16.sp,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                              color: radioButtonItem ==
                                                      _data[index].name
                                                  ? Colors.white
                                                  : const Color.fromRGBO(
                                                      44, 39, 36, 0.75),
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
```

Comment: It's not a good practice, to use radio for multiple values. Use checkbox instead. Radio is for one option in a group, checkbox is for multiple. The Radio's group parameter wont allow you to select multiple values with different value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having some trouble understanding your question. If you want to select multiple options Radiobuttons probably are not the way to go. Insted use [Checkboxes](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox-class.html) where you can select a range of different Options.

If I however misunderstood and you want a single Radiobutton to select a group of values then perhaps you should repfrase your question. Perhaps posting the kind of data you are tyring to fetch would be helpful